# How to animate my view?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Recently I saw a mobile "Karbonn Tornado" has one one application that shows applications on loading page in device as Tornado model.Means how tornado action goes in the same way here animates.Is it possible in iPhone.Please support with an example or supporting materials to do it.

Comment: please elaborate more on what you actually wants to do.

Comment: We have iphone device that show applications with paging animation.Similarly I want to show those application on single page with tornado model animation.

Comment: this is what is he referring to.. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXxUyAfJPnE

Comment: iPhone ki aisi taisi... Ya its correct.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible with openGL but even than the layout of the apps is looked out by the OS .. there is nothing you can do about it...